# assigning property type at runtime in C#

Tags: c#

I have class in which `childNodeValue` can be string or `List<ChildAttribute>` same class, if same class not supported then another class with same properties, while looping through I need to assign required type to `childNodeValue`.

```
public class ChildAttribute
{
    public int? sequence { get; set; }
    public  Type<T> childNodeValue { get; set; } // string or List<ChildAttribute>
    public int? parentId { get; set; }

}
```

How do assign type at runtime in my bellow code;

```
foreach (var pItem in pNodes)
{
    ParentAttribute pAtt = new ParentAttribute();
    pAtt.parentNodeValue = pItem["Attribute"].ToString();
    pAtt.id = Convert.ToInt32(pItem["ID"]);

    pAtt.ChildNodeValues = new List<ChildAttribute>();

    var cNodes = (from cRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where cRow.Field<decimal?>("Parent_Id") == pAtt.id
                  select cRow).ToList();


    foreach (var cItem in cNodes)
    {
        ChildAttribute cAtt = new ChildAttribute();
        // May be another foreach required here 
        cAtt.childNodeValue = cItem["Attribute"].ToString();
        cAtt.sequence = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Sequence"));
        cAtt.parentId = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Parent_Id"));

        pAtt.ChildNodeValues.Add(cAtt);
    }
    att.ParentNodes.Add(pAtt);
}
```

Comment: "I have class in which `childNodeValue` can be string or `List<ChildAttribute>` same class" - it can't at the moment, as the property type is `Type<T>`, where we don't know either what `Type<>` is, or the type parameter `T`. Perhaps you just want to make the property type `object`?

Comment: Or try defining property as `dynamic`. `public  dynamic childNodeValue { get; set; }`. If you are sure that the type of `childNodeValue` will always be some object, go with what Daisy suggested. I.e. `object childNodeValue {...}`

Comment: Can you at least provide all types that you are using?

Comment: I'd have two separate properties instead...a nodes property which is a list...and a value property which is a string

Comment: @Sefe only two types string and List<ChildAttribute>

Comment: by declaring object `object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
`

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you have a few options:

1. Declare your property as **object**.
2. Declare your property as **dynamic**.
3. Use two properties with different names, one with type **string** and another with type **List**.
4. Define a new class **ChildrenOrValue** that holds two properties. Implement an implicit type conversion to and from both **string** and **List**.

The downside of options 1 and 2 is that you'd have to check for the actual run-time type every time you try to access this property and cast those values back to the appropriate type before each use. The 4th option this is the most complex and is probably an overkill.

The third option makes the most sense:

```
public class ChildAttribute
{
    public int? sequence { get; set; }
    public List<ChildAttribute> children { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public int? parentId { get; set; }
}
```

Even though this option forces you to check which property is available every time you want to use those, it doesn't require you to downcast to the appropriate type.

Comment: Actually, in requirement, I have to change same property to `string` or `List<ChildAttribute>`

Comment: In that case, pick either 1, 2 or 4. Please let me know if you need help or an example for option 4.

Comment: `dynamic` and `object` says `does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no.....`

Comment: If you are using `object` you have to downcast back to the list. For example `cAtt.childNodeValue = new List<ChildAttribute>(); (childNodeValue as List<ChildAttribute>).Add();`